# CMAKE_BINARY_DIR not expanded correctly if build path contains spaces

Tags: build, cmake

How can I solve issues with building a project when the build path contains spaces?

The variable is set like this:

`set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR @CMAKE_BINARY_DIR@)`

and is being used a lot specially for generating the build files

`file(WRITE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeTmp/tcl_version.tcl")`

It seems it doesn't escape the space characters (e.g. "~/My Project/").

Comment: Is that in a file processed by `configure_file()`?

Comment: Add that into the question, then.

Answer (score 1):

`configure_file()` (as you've mentioned in comments that it's involved) works somewhat like the C preprocessor, in that it's textual substitution. So if you have `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` equal to e.g. `C:/Program Files`, then the configured file will look like this:

```
set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR C:/Program Files)
```

I believe it's obvious that will set `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` to a 2-element list. In a normal CMake file, you'd add quotes; so do the same for the source file being configured:

```
set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR "@CMAKE_BINARY_DIR@")
```